# How to make floatingActionButton: SpeedDial right-to-left (RTL) in flutter with changing the application language

Tags: flutter

I am trying to change the location of the SpeedDial icon while changing the application language, but it does not work.
If normal floatingActionButton is used without SpeedDial, the location is changed successfully.Attached image showing normal use of floatingActionButton:

[image]

But if SpeedDial is used, it will look like this:

[image]

I need to change the location of the SpeedDial icon while changing the Arabic language to the left.

[image]

I don’t know what the problem is. Now it does not respond to the change of language.

```
   return MaterialApp(
        localizationsDelegates:EasyLocalization.of(context).delegates,
        supportedLocales: EasyLocalization.of(context).supportedLocales,
        locale: EasyLocalization.of(context).locale,
)
```

full code:

```
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_speed_dial/flutter_speed_dial.dart';





void main() {
  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
      saveLocale: true,
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale('en', 'US'),
        Locale('ar', 'SA')],
      path: 'assets/translations',
      fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'US'),
      child: SecondScreens(),

    ),

  );

}

class SecondScreens extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  mainStates createState() => new mainStates();
}

class mainStates extends State<SecondScreens> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    {
      return MaterialApp(
        localizationsDelegates:EasyLocalization.of(context).delegates,
        supportedLocales: EasyLocalization.of(context).supportedLocales,
        locale: EasyLocalization.of(context).locale,

        home: Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton:
               SpeedDial(
            animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            children: [
              SpeedDialChild(
                  child: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFf6c626),
                  label: 'Edit',
                  ),
            ],
          ),


        ),

      );

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `Scaffold` in `Directionality` and check if language is `rtl` then mirror the screen, something like this:

```
Directionality(
  textDirection: (context.locale=='ar')?TextDirection.rtl:TextDirection.ltr,
  child: Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton:
    SpeedDial(
      animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
      shape: CircleBorder(),
      children: [
        SpeedDialChild(
          child: Icon(Icons.edit),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFf6c626),
          label: 'Edit',
        ),
      ],
    ),
    
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hello brother, thank you for your response / There is a problem after using the code that you referred to as follows:
The getter 'rtl' isn't defined for the type 'TextDirection'.//The getter 'ltr' isn't defined for the type 'TextDirection'.

Comment: @MarwanAl use `TextDirection.rtl` and check of that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Add floatingActionButtonLocation:FloatingActionButtonLocation.startFloat,property in the scaffold.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).